# Chrome Extension: opening a page without using a popup page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In an extension I'm developing, I set the manifest without the popup page, so that when you click the icon of the app in the browser's toolbar it immediately opens the app's page.

The app's  page is `index.html` and in this page I load the

`<script src="background.js"></script> & <script src="./index.js"></script>`

The `background.js` file has the following code to open the `index.html` page after the click:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
   chrome.tabs.create(
      {
         active: true,
         url: "index.html",
      },
      null
   );
});
```

also tested with: `chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL("index.html") });` , but same issue occurs.

The `manifest.json` file:

```
"background": {
      "page": "index.html",
      "persistent": false
   },

   "browser_action": {
      "browser_style": true,
      "default_icon": {
         "16": "images/icon16.png"
      }
   },
```

When I first click the icon, it opens the `index.html`, ... , but the second time I click the icon it opens 2 `index.html` files, if I click it again then it opens 4, and so on. It's ok to open another `index.html`, but just one for each icon click.

What would be the mistake I'm doing?

Thanks in advance, Ken

Comment: The problem is that you open the same background page so each new instance of the page registers a new onClicked listener and they all get triggered on the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "./background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
       
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("./page.html")
    });
});
```

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>extension page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Extension Page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, your tips fixed the issue!